# Run time exceptions in android studio start Indexing time

Tags: android, android-studio, runtimeexception

I start my Android Studio After closing. it was fine working before closing 
but Now on Starting of Android Studio "Indexing" completed full progress and again start indexing
this process is continuous Infinite level

indexing....... than,
scanning files to Index....

again

indexing....... than,
scanning files to Index...

giving Runtime Exception is:

```
 RuntimeException: java.io.IOException:writePrevChunkAddress:61889832,61981366,C:\Users\oxiloindia\.AndroidStudioPreview 2.1\system\index\trigram.index\Trigram.Index.values
```

how to stop this infinite process work of Android Studio so i can start my project

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same issue. Changing my project location and android studio restart didn't work for me. Here is the way, I resolved this issue-
**Click on File > Invalidate Caches/Restart**

Comment: I ended up needing to delete the projects cache directory. You can just delete the ```.gradle``` directory so that it can be regenerated.

Comment: First time of **Invalidate Caches/Restart** is working for me !